# EmEditor - force it to show plain text file instead of CSV?

Tags: emeditor

I have 2 log files, one of them looks fine, the other has data split into columns.

How can I make EmEditor show it plain text style?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you use the latest version of EmEditor.

Please select the **Normal mode** on the **CSV** menu, or the most left button on the **CSV** toolbar to show the current file in Normal Mode (non-CSV mode).
[image: EmEditor - Normal Mode]

If you don't want any files to open as a CSV mode, select **Properties for All Configurations** on the **Tools** menu, and clear all check boxes in the **CSV files to Detect**.
[image: EmEditor - CSV files to Detect]